# Eror handling in node js while adding data to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hey guys i am trying to handle errors during user signup module in express but somehow the error is not handled correctly.
here is my code for that

```
handler.post(async (req, res) => {
  let otp = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedpassword = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, salt);
  data["password"] = hashedpassword;
  data["otp"] = otp;
  data["active"] = false;
  delete data.confirmPassword;

  try {
    const emailexist = await req.db
      .collection("users")
      .findOne({ email: data.email });
    if (emailexist) {
      return res.status(401).send('email already exits')
    } else {
      let doc = await req.db.collection("users").insertOne(data);
      res.json(doc.ops[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(401).send("Error while adding");
  }
});
```

so as u can see there are two chances of error once if the email exist and then if that is the case i am sending back error

Second chance is that if any error occur during the insertion time for that too in catch block i am sending error but somehow when i encounter the first error that is "if the email already exists" still in my frontend i am getting response of "Eror while adding"

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it , so if the user already exists you sent back a json with a status `400` (Bad request,indicating that the server cannot or will not process the request)

```
  if (emailexist) {
  return res.status(400).json({error:"User Already Exists"})
  }
```

and in the catch you sent it with a status `500`  indicating something went wrong on the server side

```
  res.status(500).send("Server error");
```